# Where to find full list of metadata options in mongoengine?

Tags: mongoengine

I want to find the full list of meta options one can set while defining documents in mongoengine but I am not able to find them all in one place. They are all scattered throughout the mongoengine documentation and many meta options are not even mentioned.

Where can I find the full list of meta options in one consolidated page?

Examples of meta options are `meta = {'strict': False}`